# Which technology was used for?

Tags: frontend

Sorry for stupid question. I'm learning frontend and backend technology. I'd like to do apps like this easy, but i don't undertand how that was made.

https://thelucky777.site/

It's look very simple only few blocks, but index.css have more then 10 000 lines of code. It has a lot  selectors name wb_layoutgrid54, wb_layoutgrid16 etc.
I know react a little and django.
My question is how can i do apps like this without headache? How that app was made?

Comment: Do you have an actual question?  The base frameworks used are jQuery and Bootstrap, which is fairly common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a look at the site, I would be fairly certain this can be achieved using plain HTML, CSS and some Javascript/jQuery to help with the animations.

When it comes to development, my personal opinion is take for example a site, it can be developed many ways using different tools to achieve the same outcome. To make this less of a headache I would develop a wireframe and break things down step by step what you need to do without thinking what tool(s) was used and once you get an outline start to slowly build and research how to do certain sections using your skillset.

Overall I will still state that it can be done using basic tools such as HTML, CSS and some Javascript.

I hope this helps :)